# How to get vim-rails' :Rake to run bin/rspec?

Tags: vim, macvim

- [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) 376773 (14 Oct 2014), incl. [vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails)
- MacVim 7.4(73)
- rails 4.1.6
- rspec 3.1.0
- [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) 1.1.3
- [spring-commands-rspec](https://github.com/jonleighton/spring-commands-rspec) 1.0.2

I have spring binstubs, including `bin/rake` and `bin/rspec`

In general, running `:Rake` runs `bin/rake` -- yay (cf [vim-rails #253](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues/253)).

Running `:Rake` while editing a `_spec.rb` file, however, runs `rspec` from the gem's folder: `.../ruby ... .../rspec-core-3.1.6/exe/rspec`. This produces different output/errors than when run as `bin/rspec` or `spring rspec` (as suggested by [guard-spec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#options)).

How can I get `:Rake` to run `bin/rspec` so I can see the same output/errors from within MacVim/`mvim` and `guard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing a spec file, `vim-rails`' `:Rrunner` invokes `bin/rspec` directly, thus producing the same output & errors as when run by `guard`.

`vim-rails`' `:Rake` invokes `bin/rake spec SPEC=...`, which ends up invoking the `ruby` and `rspec` paths as shown in the question -- thus the different environment, errors, & output than the `spring`-ified `bin/rspec` or `spring rspec` as run by `guard`.

Comment: Overwriting my ':Rake' muscle-memory is a 'personal' and not SO-appropriate 'problem' :-)

Comment: I searched all the internet for this...  only when I was writting my question in stackoverflow, crying all my tears, this question showed up.

In my case, I was trying to run my specs using `:Rails` and it didnt go through spring.  
`:Runner` solved my problems. Thanks. It was not easy to figure out through help docs.